# how do i fix "org.jboss.ws.WSException: is not a valid property on class" without javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have an application that deploys locally just fine, but throws `org.jboss.ws.WSException:  {http://shared.url/uniquePart/}XmlBean is not a valid property on class` when i put it on a shared jboss.

(I tried declaring namespaces everywhere to reduce conflicts. )

Everything says to use @RequesWrapper to avoid this problem, but I have more than one parameter as input and I don't know how to use @RequesWrapper with more than one className

```
@Clustered
@Stateless(name = "Publisher", description = "...")
@WebService(name = "Publisher", serviceName = "Publisher", targetNamespace="http://shared.url/uniquePart/")
@WebContext(contextRoot="CantChangeThis")
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="Publisher/remote")
public class PublisherBean implements PublisherRemote 
{   

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "Published")
    @Override
    public boolean sendPublish(
        @WebParam(name = "XmlBean", targetNamespace="http://shared.url/uniquePart/") XmlBean1 xml1, 
        @WebParam(name = "someString") String stringName,
        @WebParam(name = "XmlBean2") XmlBean2 xml2) {
             ....
    }}
```

this deploys fine locally, but in a shared environment blows up, saying XmlBean is not a valid property on class mypackage.jaxws.SendPublish

As far as I can tell, I can put XmlBean, the String, and XmlBean2 into another class my.MyOtherClass and use `@RequesWrapper(className='my.MyOtherClass')` to fix this, but this is a pervasive problem though the entire deployment and I hope there is a better way of doing this such that I don't have to get rid of all the methods that take more than one simple argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.jboss.ws.WSException: {http://shared.url/uniquePart/}XmlBean is not a valid property on class` error ended up being a class loading conflict totally unrelated to the code and question at hand.

This was solved by adding a "[jboss-classloading.xml](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/)" file and setting parent-first to 'true'